# Access parent item inside a loop in jsrender

Tags: jsrender

```
<select id="Test" TestAttr="{{:LocationId}}">              
       {{for #parent.parent.data.Location}}                         
                  <option value="{{:LocationId}}" {{if LocationId= *#parent.parent.data.LocationId*}}selected{{/if}}>{{:#parent.parent.data.LocationId}}</option>                            
       {{/for}}
</select>
```

How to get the parent array's LocationId inside if statement which is mentioned in between **.

Comment: If i give {{:#parent.parent.data.LocationId}} inside option tag i am able to see value of it. But i want to consume the same in if statement.

Comment: Location is the child array which has the values to create dropdown.

Answer (score 13):

You can introduce variable which will be visible inside loop
(In official documentation: [Setting contextual template parameters, accessible in all nested contexts as ~nameOfParameter](http://borismoore.github.com/jsrender/demos/step-by-step/11_accessing-parent-data.html))

```
<select id="Test" TestAttr="{{:LocationId}}">  
    {{for #parent.parent.data.Location ~locationId=LocationId}}
       <option value="{{:~locationId}}"...
```

---

***EDITED POSTSCRIPT:***

The above link is to previous documentation, now superceded.

For current documentation, see [Accessing parent data](https://www.jsviews.com/#parentdata).

See also this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34953167/1054484)

Comment: Thanks for replying. How do I use this in if statement?

Comment: {{if LocationId == ~locationId }}