# How to access parent data properties in JsRender nested templates

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jsrender

http://jsfiddle.net/tQnVt/621/

This fiddle illustrates my problem.

Say I am binding a JSON onto view with the help of jsrender templates.

```
var vm = {
    foo: {color: "red",otherObjectToMatch:"object"},
    testData: [{color: "red"}, {color: "yellow"}, {color: "blue"}]
};
```

Object `vm` has 2 properties- 
1) a plain object
2) array of objects.

**Template-**

```
<script id="template" type="text/x-jsrender">
    <p>
    {{:foo.color}}
    </p>
    <ul>
    {{for testData}}
        <li>index: {{>color}}</li>
    {{/for}}
    </ul>
</script>
```

I want to match from plain object `#1` by its property where if its property color matches with the property in loop then will apply some class.

**I tried-**

```
 <p>
    {{:foo.color}}
    </p>
    <ul>
    {{for testData}}
       {{if foo.color=={{>color}} }}
         <li class='match'>index: {{>color}}</li>
       {{else}}
         <li>index: {{>color}}</li>
       {{/if}}
    {{/for}}
    </ul>
```

This is a failed try. I can't find how to match with other objects in jsrender.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to write

```
{{if xxx.foo.color===color}}
```

where `xxx` is the parent data - in your case the `vm` you passed in as root data.

(It's all about the '*view hierarchy*' - see: http://www.jsviews.com/#views. See also the specific topic [Accessing parent data](https://www.jsviews.com/#parentdata))

Here are several different ways to get to the data on the parent view:

Access `~root` which is a shortcut helper for the root data:

```
{{for testData}}
   {{if ~root.foo.color===color}} 
     <li class='match'>index: {{>color}} (match)</li>
   {{else}}
     <li>index: {{>color}}</li>
   {{/if}}
{{/for}}
```

Create a contextual template parameter `~foo` to pass the `foo` property from parent data through to the nested template contexts:

```
{{for testData ~foo=foo}}
   {{if ~foo.color===color}}
     <li class='match'>index: {{>color}} (match)</li>
   {{else}}
     <li>index: {{>color}}</li>
   {{/if}}
{{/for}}
```

Step up through the parent `view` objects, and get the data view:

```
{{for testData}}
   {{if #parent.parent.data.foo.color===color}}
     <li class='match'>index: {{>color}} (match)</li>
   {{else}}
     <li>index: {{>color}}</li>
   {{/if}}
{{/for}}
```

Use the `view.get()` helper to find the parent of view of type `"data"`

```
{{for testData}}
   {{if #get("data").data.foo.color===color}}
     <li class='match'>index: {{>color}} (match)</li>
   {{else}}
     <li>index: {{>color}}</li>
   {{/if}}
{{/for}}
```

I added all of them to your jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tQnVt/625/

See also this related reply: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34441881/1054484

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can to use `#parent`.
Please see [link](https://www.jsviews.com/#parentdata) to the docs.