# Use parent object property inside helper object loop Jsrender

Tags: jquery, jsrender

I am sending a object **branchData** in ajax response to jsrender template having branch details.

```
branchData: Array(2)
0: {name: "M13", displayName: "Abc", url: null}
1: {name: "M01", displayName: "Xyz", url: null}
```

with

```
var helper = {
branchHoursText: "Teléfono y Horarios"
phoneText: "Teléfono"
hoursText: "Horario"
closedText: "CERRADA"
inventory: {M01: "0", M13: "1", M11: "0", M10: "0", M21: "0"} 
}

$(".branchInfo").html(branchTemplate.render(response, helpers));
```

I am using following code in template.

```
{{for branchData}}
     {{:displayName}}

    {{props ~inventory}}

    {{/props}}
{{/for}}
```

I want to display inventory of that branch if **branchData.name == inventory.key**. Something like

```
{{props ~inventory}}
        {{if key === name}}
            {{>prop}}
        {{/if}}}
{{/props}}
```

please help !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to access parent data (`name`) from inside the `{{props}}` tag. There are a few alternative approaches you can use. See [Accessing parent data](https://www.jsviews.com/#parentdata).

For example:

```
{{for branchData}}
    {{:displayName}}

    {{props ~inventory ~itemName=name}}
        {{if key === ~itemName}}
            {{>prop}}
        {{/if}}
    {{/props}}
{{/for}}
```

or

```
{{for branchData itemVar="~branchItem"}}
    {{:displayName}}:

    {{props ~inventory}}
        {{if key === ~branchItem.name}}
            {{>prop}}
        {{/if}}
    {{/props}}
{{/for}}
```

See also this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34953167/1054484)